# About Lebesgue-measure and regularity.

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, compactness, outer-measure

Let $\lambda=l^{*}$ the Lebesgue measure in $\Bbb{R}$, and $A$ a Lebesgue-measurable subset of $\Bbb{R}$ with $\lambda(A)<\infty.$

If $\epsilon>0,$ I need to prove that exists an open set $G$ which is the union of a finite number of open intervals such that 
$$||\chi_{A}-\chi_{G} ||_{1}=|\lambda(A)-\lambda(G)|<\epsilon. $$
Moreover, exists a continuous function $f$ such that $$||\chi_{A}-f ||_{1}=\int|\chi_{A}-f|d\lambda <\epsilon. $$

The exercise asks to use the following exercises, that I already did it:
[image]

What I did:

By exercise 9.G, exists an open set $G_{\epsilon}$ such that $A\subset G_{\epsilon}$ and $$\lambda(A)\leq \lambda(G_{\epsilon})\leq\lambda(A)+\epsilon $$

By exercise 9.H, exists a compact set $K_{\epsilon}\subset A$ such that $$\lambda(K_{\epsilon})\leq \lambda(A)\leq \lambda(K_{\epsilon})+\epsilon.$$

Now, I will use the compactness of $K_{\epsilon}.$ If $(A_{i})_{i\in I}$ is an open cover of $K_{\epsilon}$ such that every $A_{i}$ is an open interval, with $A_{i}\subset G_{\epsilon}$, we can extract a finite subcover $(A_{i})_{i\in\Bbb{N}}$ of $K_{\epsilon}$.

Define $G=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_{i}.$ So, we have

$$\lambda(K_{\epsilon})\leq\lambda(G)\leq\lambda(A)\leq\lambda(K_{\epsilon})+\epsilon
  $$

I don't know what to do from here. My construction of $G$ is the set asked for the exercise? What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We denote $\triangle $ the symmetric difference $A \triangle B=(A \setminus B) \cup( B \setminus A)$

Since $A$ has a finite measure and is measurable, then $\forall \epsilon>0$, exist disjoint open intervals $J_1,...,J_m$ such that $m(A \triangle \bigcup_{k=1}^mJ_k)<\epsilon$

Thus $$\int |1_A-1_G| = \int|1_{A \triangle G}|=m(A \triangle G)<\epsilon$$

We have that $1_G=\sum_{k=1}^{m}J_k$

Now  you can easily approximate $1_G$ by a continuous function which is piecewise affinic.

Comment: How can I prove your first statement?
"Since $A$ has finite measure and is measurable, then $\forall\,\epsilon>0$, exist disjoint open intervals $J_{1},\dots,J_{m}$ such that $m(A\triangle\bigcup_{k=1}^{m}J_{k})<\epsilon$"

Comment: @MateusRocha.. This is the first littelwood principle..informaly says that every measurable set of finite measure is almost a union of intervals...you can find a proof of this in many textbooks